# Real life use of union in c programming Language?

Tags: c, union

I am not able to find out the *real life* use of ***union*** in c language ? Also i try to find on *google* but i am not able to get any answers ?

Comment: You can use a union in C anywhere you have two things and want to store one or the other in the same memory location, because you're always going to have either one or the other of the two things, but not both.  It avoids you from having to allocate memory for both things when you know you're only going to store one.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux, just run `grep 'union' /usr/include/* -rn`, you can find many `union` type declared.

Here is a example I extract from file `/usr/include/netinet/in.h`. It represent IPv6 address. IPv6 address is 16 bytes, This declare make use of union to give you thress different ways to access it.

```
struct in6_addr
  {
    union
      {   
    uint8_t __u6_addr8[16];
#if defined __USE_MISC || defined __USE_GNU
    uint16_t __u6_addr16[8];
    uint32_t __u6_addr32[4];
#endif
      } __in6_u;
#define s6_addr         __in6_u.__u6_addr8
#if defined __USE_MISC || defined __USE_GNU
# define s6_addr16      __in6_u.__u6_addr16
# define s6_addr32      __in6_u.__u6_addr32
#endif
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

The [X Windows `XEvent`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/include/X11/Xlib.h.html#969) is one widely used on most Unix/Linux systems:

```
/*
 * this union is defined so Xlib can always use the same sized
 * event structure internally, to avoid memory fragmentation.
 */
typedef union _XEvent {
        int type;       /* must not be changed; first element */
        XAnyEvent xany;
        XKeyEvent xkey;
        XButtonEvent xbutton;
        XMotionEvent xmotion;
        XCrossingEvent xcrossing;
        XFocusChangeEvent xfocus;
        XExposeEvent xexpose;
        XGraphicsExposeEvent xgraphicsexpose;
        XNoExposeEvent xnoexpose;
        XVisibilityEvent xvisibility;
        XCreateWindowEvent xcreatewindow;
        XDestroyWindowEvent xdestroywindow;
        XUnmapEvent xunmap;
        XMapEvent xmap;
        XMapRequestEvent xmaprequest;
        XReparentEvent xreparent;
        XConfigureEvent xconfigure;
        XGravityEvent xgravity;
        XResizeRequestEvent xresizerequest;
        XConfigureRequestEvent xconfigurerequest;
        XCirculateEvent xcirculate;
        XCirculateRequestEvent xcirculaterequest;
        XPropertyEvent xproperty;
        XSelectionClearEvent xselectionclear;
        XSelectionRequestEvent xselectionrequest;
        XSelectionEvent xselection;
        XColormapEvent xcolormap;
        XClientMessageEvent xclient;
        XMappingEvent xmapping;
        XErrorEvent xerror;
        XKeymapEvent xkeymap;
        XGenericEvent xgeneric;
        XGenericEventCookie xcookie;
        long pad[24];
} XEvent;
```

Every event in an X Windows system is an `XEvent` union.